# Audit failed login attempts to domain on Active Directory controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, authentication

I want to get information about all failed login attempts on Active directory server.
I already changed these policies on AD controller:[image]

And disabled **Audit: Force Audit policy subcategory settings (Windows Vista or Later)** on client and controller machines.

After these actions I can see only success attempts login to Domain in Event Viewer(in Security page) from client machines on domain controller(failed attempts I can see only in Security log of client machine). 
What am I doing wrong? How can I see these attempts in security log of Active Directory controller as well?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the new subcategory settings - they are more dynamic and much more flexible.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't allow determination of which policy is being edited. Since the policy is "correct" have to assume wrong policy is being edited. Normally this is handled by "Default Domain Controllers Policy". Is that the policy your editing?

Answer (score 3):

I would use the subcategories - they're more advanced, flexible, configurable, and appropriate.

Here are the settings that you would be looking to enable (in addition to "enabling" the forcing of the subcategory use).  Though, you really only need the credential validation entry.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Is option "Audit: Force Audit policy subcategory settings (Windows Vista or Later)" needed for that as well?

Comment: It would certainly be preferred, to ensure any legacy settings are ignored.